# AST for any arbitrary programming language or IR

Tags: c++, c, yacc, lex, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to create an AST for any arbitrary programming language or IR using C or C++ alone (without the help of tools like YACC and LEX )?

If so, how to implement the lexical and syntactic analysis ?

If not, what are the tools that have to augmented to C or C++ to successfully create an AST ?

Hope I made my doubt clear. If My question looks vague or out of context, please indicate the required.

P.S : I Am actually trying to create the AST for the LLVM's .ll format of IR representation. I do know that .ll is derived from AST. But I am trying out static analysis practices. So I am looking at creating the AST.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You can create program that creates an abstract syntax tree for any programming language in any programming language. How that's exactly done is a huge area of study in computer science.

Comment: Of course it's possible... C++ is an ideal language for implementing compilers, an AST is a simple first step in that direction. The question really ought to be about the available libraries to kick-start the process for you, but which is suitable depends a lot on your exact needs. Do you want to implement a particular language, or have a flexible framework for defining multiple languages? Have you looked at boost spirit?

Comment: @In Silico: I Am actually trying to create the AST for the LLVM's .ll format of IR representation. 

I do know that .ll is derived from AST. But I am trying out static analysis practices. So I am looking at creating the AST.

Comment: Why is important to create ASTs without using YACC (or implied, without using a parser generator)?  Parser Generators are your friend, and make it easy to build parsers, especially for custom languages.

Comment: Actually I wanted to convert the LLVM .ll format to a XML representation and try out some static analysis step and convert it back to the .ll format .

Comment: Actually I wanted to convert the LLVM .ll format to a XML representation and try some static analysis and convert it back to the .ll format .

My main aim was to get the XML representation of the LLVM format rather creating a parser.

Comment: At this point , I would like to ask some basic question which might clear some of the black-hole spots in my understanding since I am new to LLVM 

1. The emit-llvm option , does it emit the .ll form of the code without any modification ? ( apart from preprocessing)

2. I was able to find one command "clang -cc1 <.c file> -ast-print-xml .... ".This command does throw the XML format. And it contains loads of information. I am not sure if all of that would be necessary. Would it be?

I am newbie to this. I am trying to understand it so tat I may not have a stupid mis-conception. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward methodology for creating the parser without a parser-generator is [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).  It is very well documented - the standard book in the field is [The Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886).

A scanner, that takes text as input and produces a string of tokens as output, can be written using standard string manipulation techniques.

Comment: I will look into it and probably be back with question if any.

Comment: The bottom-up parsing is only slightly less intuitive. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing    Once you get the whole idea of shift-reduce algorithms, it does not seem harder than the top-down parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a one-to-one mapping between your arbitrary langauge and LLVM's ASTs.
That means it is likely that you really want to do this in two stages:

- Parse your 'arbitrary language' using the best parsing tools  you can get to simplify the problem of parsing your language.  Use that to build an AST for *your* language, following standard methods for parser generators producing ASTs.   LEX/YACC are OK but there are  plenty of good alternatives out there.  Its pretty likely you'll need to build a symbol table.
- Walk the AST of the your parsed langauge to build your LLVM AST.  This won't be one-to-one, but the ability to look around the tree near a tree node in your AST to collect information need to generate the LLVM code will likely be extremely helpful.

This is a classic style for a simple compiler.

I suggest you read the Aho/Ullman Dragon book on syntax directed translation.  A day's worth of education will save you months of wasted engineering time.

Comment: I read that book some few years back. I think almost 3 years back ( the first edition). But I bought a second edition, have not gone through the book yet. 

I guess the SDT was not discussed in detail in first edition, isnt ?

Second edition has so many other things too. I need to read the book again I guess

Comment: I answered the question before you clarified you want to manipulate the LLVM IL.   In this case, you can pretty much design a one-for-one text syntax for each element of the LLVM IL (e.g, your notion of using XML).   In that case, you can likely build a parser that folds the "walk the AST step" into the parsing actions themselves; this is called "on the fly" code generation and is what really simple SDTs do.